# "The connection was reset" only in Firefox when http post back

Tags: security, firefox

Our customer has Single Sign On implementation with Shibboleth. that post assertion back to our server on cloud. it works properly in IE, Chrome, ... but always fail on Firefox recently.

The error is famous "The connection was reset", I searched lots of discussion about this error, and found a workaround by change Firefox security setting as following:

1. open the firefox, clear all the cookies and caches, then point to about:config
2. search and set both “security.ssl3.rsa_aes_128_sha” and “security.ssl3.rsa_aes_256_sha” to false (by double click these item in the about:config window)

After change above 2 security settings, the issue is solved in firefox, everything is ok. But we can't suggest our customer to change their Firefox security setting. I am wondering why above two items caused "The connection was reset" error, can we have a solution on our server or Shibboleth ID server?

Really appreciate any suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

I just experienced the same problem but with SimpleSAMLPHP. The problem was only in firefox and only on the postback of the SAML Response.

For us the reason for the error was that out LB had a cap on how much data it allowed in the header. Firefox adds more header data than the other browsers and the SAML Response was big enough to reach the cap.

After changing the cap, everything works fine.

Comment: I'm having a similiar issue, it might be related - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30998981/post-redirect-throws-a-connection-was-reset-browser-error